# Validation rule for Date/Time Opened must trigger if a date is greater than 08/10/2022

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I am trying to create a validation rule that will work with other criteria however I am stuck on how to create formula for the rule to fire when the Date/Time opened field is greater than 08/10/2022.

My formula so far:

```text
AND(
  RecordType.Name = "WP Implementation",
  ISBLANK(Kick_Off_Meeting__c),
  ISPICKVAL( Status , "Setup")
)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Where exactly are you getting stuck? Determining the right field, the syntax for the validation, or how to check against a specific date? Updating your question with this information will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It will be great if you can provide more information. As per my understanding, you can try something like this -

```text
AND(
  RecordType.Name = "WP Implementation", 
  ISBLANK(Kick_Off_Meeting__c), 
  ISPICKVAL( Status , "Setup"), 
  OpenedDate__c > DATE(year,month,day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys managed to get it working:

```text
AND(
  DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) > Date(2022,08,10),
  RecordType.Name = "WP Implementation",
  ISBLANK(Kick_Off_Meeting__c),
  ISPICKVAL( Status , "Setup")
)
```